# PDF Compression like smallpdf.com programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, compression

I am using Itextsharp for C# to stamp information/merge fields into a pdf.
This is working well.

My problems is that that the pdfs are a little large, 1.1M sometimes. I would like to make them smaller. I tried compression for ItextSharp but did not help that much.

I found a website called smallpdf.com which i can just drag it and it does a wonderful job in compressing them. It is exactly what I want, except i want to do it programmatically, because I am emailing the files afterwards.

Anyone know if they have a c# version or is there any other software you guys can suggest that just compresses the file? I dont mind paying a reasonable amount if it gets results like smallpdf.com and its easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can compress PDF files with ghostscript:

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER \
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
    -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 \
    -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen \
    -dEmbedAllFonts=true \
    -dSubsetFonts=true \
    -dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
    -dColorImageResolution=144 \
    -dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
    -dGrayImageResolution=144 \
    -dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
    -dMonoImageResolution=144 \
    -sOutputFile=OUTPUT.pdf INPUT.pdf
```

Comment: Awesome, been looking for these GS settings for a while.

Answer (score 0):

ABCpdf has a ReduceSize operation which will do this.

It includes features for resizing and recompressing images at different DPIs and using different compression schemes including JPEG2000 and JBIG2.

It can remove embedded fonts including identity encoding fonts.

Plus it does all the other normal compression bits and bobs.

http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf9net/source/8-abcpdf.operations/b-reducesizeoperation/

I work on the ABCpdf .NET software component so my replies may feature concepts based around ABCpdf. It's just what I know. :-)